# CSS rule that applies if an element has a line break?

Tags: css

In the image below, the red text is all `<li>` elements. I'm going to add `margin-bottom` to the first one, "Web development projects." But I guess it would be much neater to add `margin-bottom` to any `<li>` element that contains a line break, i.e. that takes up more than one line.

Please tell me that I'm crazy and that this is impossible to do with CSS alone.

(I'm happy to share the HTML/CSS but I promise there's nothing out of the ordinary there.)

[image]

Comment: You can't detect line breaks with CSS. _I think_

Comment: Can you show us what your code looks like so that we can see the structure and help you out a little more

Comment: @Enjayy I'm happy to, just didn't want to dump reams of code into SO. You can have a look at [alesh.com/projects](http://alesh.com/projects). The elements in question are simple `li` items, and the css is just removing bullets and doing some little font tweaks. The view in question is a style sheet that kicks in for widths of under 500px.

Answer (score -1):

this should work https://jsfiddle.net/v5gLf3cL/1/

```
br {
   display: block;
   content: " ";
   margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I meant when an element breaks on it's own, not when there's a break character inserted manually...